# Google Datastudio: Apply Date Range Filter for Two Different Date Columns of Date Source

Tags: looker-studio

I have a requirement to have date range filter which can be used for two different date columns of the data source(One at a time either through radio button to choose at which column date range should apply).

Is it possible to achieve this in Google Data studio ?

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

The general idea is to use let the user set the value of a parameter, which determines the value of a dummy field containing the value of either datetime column. You can then indicate that your table/chart should filter by this datetime field.

1. Create a *parameter* in the data source, with the names of the columns you want as possible values. If you want to filter the `order_date` and `completed_date` columns, these should be possible options.
2. Allow the user to set the parameter (e.g. by using a radio button).
3. Create a *calculated* field in the data source (e.g. `select_date`) which, depending on the value of the parameter. For example, create a field `user_field`:

```
CASE user_select                              # this is a parameter
    WHEN "order_date" THEN order_date         # this is the value of the order_date field
    WHEN "completed_date" THEN completed_date # this is the value of the completed_date field
    ELSE NULL
END
```

4. Set the 'Date Range Dimension' of your chart/table to `user_field` (the name of the calculated field).

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Actual output)? It would help users visualise the suggestion. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to understand exactly what the fields are and the steps taken, at a glance

Answer (score -1):

**Workaround**:

If the table has a primary key, you can make a datablending with itself and in a data set put as a time filter a first field and in the other with the second field.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Hhv.png)

After that, you should add the metrics and dimensions you need from one of them.

Now when you apply a time filter, it will work on both of them.

Comment: Can you add more details/examples? What does the final blended report look like? How do you add it to the report and have a date filter on both? From your example, it looks like if you filter on a date then it will apply to both date fields at the same time? So you couldn't filter on one column with one date and another column with a different date range?