# How can I apply 2 date controls on report/page level?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to know if it is possible to have 2 date range controls on my page. Each date range control would be connected to a different date (`Purchase date` / `Consumption date`) of our products).

[Here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/12ecda77-7e06-47bd-a6a9-a39088094ad6) is a simplified editable copy of the data studio report.

The Google Sheet source looks like:

| ID | Purchase date | Consumption date | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD12 | 21/03/2022 | 09/11/2022 | A | £50 |
| EFGH34 | 22/03/2022 | 22/11/2022 | B | £80 |
| IJKL56 | 23/04/2022 | 15/11/2022 | A | £50 |
| MNOP78 | 24/03/2022 | 06/12/2022 | A | £50 |

The output I'm looking for is to be able to filter data so that I can answer the question "how many products were purchased in March 2022 that have a consumption date in November 2022". The expected output is as follows:

| ID | Purchase date | Consumption date | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD12 | 21/03/2022 | 09/11/2022 | A | £50 |
| EFGH34 | 22/03/2022 | 22/11/2022 | B | £80 |

Supermetrics has a Date Picker that essentially does what I need it to do. But it has 2 downsides 1) it is bulky and does not work well with many years of data and 2) It does not allow breaking down to more than a monthly level.

Is there another way to make this happen with parameters?

[Through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008318/google-datastudio-apply-date-range-filter-for-two-different-date-columns-of-dat/71201104#71201104) I've gotten as far as getting a 'switch' for my graphs and tables between the two date datapoints, but that is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

actually you did find already a good solution by the 3rd party Add-one "Date Picker" from Supermetrics. An alternative route is to include two tables which only have the consumption date as a column. The user can then select these and do a cross filtering of the main table.

[image]

In the first table, the dimension has to be changed to "Year Month":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative [community visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) to the [Date Picker](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1_zdV7RiWNR3BPEc0xhVFFFsFYppEFw3s/page/YjI4) (based on the limitations cited in the question) would be the [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB).

Two Range Sliders could be used (one for each date field), however, the below will use one [Date range control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) and one Range Slider to demonstrate that they can work together (as well as maintaining the original setup in the question):

## 1) `Purchase date`

#### 1.1) [Date range control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067)

#### 1.2) [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)

- ***Date Range Dimension***: `Purchase date`
- ***Dimension 1***: `ID`
- ***Dimension 2***: `Purchase date`
- ***Dimension 3***: `Consumption date`
- ***Dimension 4***: `Product`
- ***Metric***: `Price`

## 2) `Consumption date`

#### 2.1) [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB)

- ***Column to filter on***: `Consumption date`
- (Chart Interactions) ***Cross Filtering***: ☑

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3566a196-a629-460d-8672-70c39edd424d) (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m4phkKeyarc4QWvSqVKino0EFcDOzv7KyEtb1HW_Wpw/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]